# sendgrid event timestamp - delivered before bounced

Tags: sendgrid

I am seeing many instances where the email has been delivered before a bounce event, the difference though is in few seconds. Essentially I can see delivered time as 1493678489 and bounced time as 1493678510 which doesn't seem right because a bounce shouldn't happen if there is delivery or even if it retries after the first bounce, the event timestamp of bounce should be less than the delivered.
Did anyone faced this issue.[See the pasted image as an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6Umb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is covered in [their documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Deliver/Undeliverable_Email/why_did_my_message_show_as_delivered_first_then_as_bounced.html).

Comment: Thanks @jacobmovingfwd